# How to format signed currency

Tags: c#

I have the following scenario. A decimal value needs to be displayed as a currency but include the appropriate currency symbol and sign, thus:

1. -45.23 is displayed as -£45.23
2. 45.23 is displayed as +£45.23

The currency sign must come from `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol`. I have this, but I can't find a way to swap the sign and currency symbol:

```
string s1 = string.Format(@"{1}{0:+#,##0.00;-#,##0.00}", 45.09M, 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol);
Console.WriteLine(s2);
string s2 = string.Format(@"{1}{0:+#,##0.00;-#,##0.00}", -45.09M, 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol);
Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

Outputs:

```
£+45.09
£-45.09
```

I want:

```
+£45.09
-£45.09
```

## UPDATE

Someone posted another answer regarding the [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyPositivePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern.aspx) Property, which looked promising, especially since the but it appears that Microsoft overlooked the possibility that the [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyNegativePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx) Property contains various options for the presentation of the negative sign. However, the `NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyPositivePattern` does not include an option to include the positive sign! Damn. Thanks to whoever it was that mentioned it, but deleted their comments. I learnt someone nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `string.Format` is *explicitly* putting the +/- at the front.

If you split the operation into two steps, it becomes easier.  First inject your currentcy symbol, then format your number.

```
string fmt = string.Format(@"{{0:+{0}#,##0.00;-{0}#,##0.00}}",  
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol);
string s1 = string.Format(fmt, 45.09M);
Console.WriteLine(s1); 
string s2 = string.Format(fmt, -45.09M);
Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

Comment: I want the string.Format explicitly display the `+/-`. Is that what you meant? I actually liked your idea. I converted this into an extension method. Two `string.Format` calls, but at least it is more readable.

Comment: You could also cache the format string, if you're not likely to change currency.

Comment: It felt a bit weird giving the answer to myself. All yours.

Answer (score 3):

As I posted this, I realised the answer is to do this in three steps instead of two:

```
string s1 = string.Format(@"{0:+;-}{1}{0:#,##0.00;#,##0.00}", 45.09M, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol);
Console.WriteLine(s1);

string s2 = string.Format(@"{0:+;-}{1}{0:#,##0.00;#,##0.00}", -45.09M, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol);
Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

Outputs:

```
+£45.09
-£45.09
```

Comment: I think there is a smiley face somewhere in there.